# NSJSONSerialization with NO Options

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I've used this in several projects...

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someObject options:0 error:nil]
```

but I don't know how to specify `no options`. This is both for reading and writing.

I saw an example somewhere where the person had used a constant value instead of just `0` but I can't find it.

Is there a way to properly specify no options?

AppCode displays a warning if I use the above code.

Comment: A value of `0` means "no options". There is no specific enum value provided by Apple for "no options".

Comment: I thought that was the case but when I used it in AppCode it didn't like me not using the correct enum. I'll just live with the warning, thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy There is, it's called `kNilOptions`.

Comment: @H2CO3 There is no such symbol in the iOS docs. Maybe it is only available under OSX. Update: Though it seems the symbol can be used in iOS without any added imports. Good to know.

Comment: @rmaddy I have it in `<MacTypes.h>` in the iPhoneOS5.1.sdk folder.

Comment: @H2CO3 To clarify, `kNilOptions` is not in the iOS documentation but the symbol can be used in an iOS app. `<MacTypes.h>` must be included ultimately by `Foundation.h`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `kNilOptions`. Ray Wenderlich uses it in his [iOS JSON tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5), and I've used it without issues.

`kNilOptions` is defined in `MacTypes.h`:

```
enum {
   kNilOptions = 0
};
```

Since `NSJSONReadingOptions` is an enum, `kNilOptions` is suitable, and as Ray Wenderlich points out in the tutorial, it's more descriptive than simply `0`:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someObject
                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Options 0 is fine, that's what I use in Xcode anyway.  It does not complain.